# Not able to take input of numbers from notepad in my code

Tags: c++, gcc, file-io, numbers, atom-editor

My code is (using [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor))):

Kindly *note* all the errors have been removed, but the output is wrong. At the end of the question, the output is listed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char ch ;
  int a, arr[2], i=0;
  ifstream f(“num.txt”);
  while(!f.eof())
  {
    f>>ch;
    arr[i]=a;
  }
  f.close();
  for(int i = 0 ; i<3 ; i++)
  {
    cout<<a[i]<<'\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The data of 'num.txt' is '123'.

```
Error:
C:\Users\sy304\Documents\CPP\num_text.cpp:10:14: error: stray '\342' in program
ifstream f(“num.txt”);
^
C:\Users\sy304\Documents\CPP\num_text.cpp:10:15: error: stray '\200' in program
ifstream f(“num.txt”);
^
C:\Users\sy304\Documents\CPP\num_text.cpp:10:16: error: stray '\234' in program
ifstream f(“num.txt”);
^
C:\Users\sy304\Documents\CPP\num_text.cpp:10:24: error: stray '\342' in program
ifstream f(“num.txt”);
^
C:\Users\sy304\Documents\CPP\num_text.cpp:10:25: error: stray '\200' in program
ifstream f(“num.txt”);
^
C:\Users\sy304\Documents\CPP\num_text.cpp:10:26: error: stray '\235' in program
ifstream f(“num.txt”);
^
C:\Users\sy304\Documents\CPP\num_text.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\sy304\Documents\CPP\num_text.cpp:10:17: error: 'num' was not declared in this scope
ifstream f(“num.txt”);
^~~
C:\Users\sy304\Documents\CPP\num_text.cpp:19:14: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
cout<<a[i]<<'\n';
^
```

I am new to Atom. How can I get the solution for these errors?

Output:

```
51
1982955789
859839168
```

Comment: Looks like you're using some non-ascii quotes. Here, use these: `"num.txt"`.

Comment: Can you put the stack trace in a code block so it doesn't look so jumbled.

Comment: "Notepad" is not a text editor that's suitable for writing and editing C++ code. You need a real text editor.

Comment: @SameerYadav I wasn't kidding about my comment. If you replace your smart quotes with the regular quotes I provided it will clear up those errors.

Comment: @John It would appear you knowingly answered the question in the comments? Comments are intended to ask for more information or to suggest improvements, not for answering questions. If a you have an answer to a question that warrants an answer, post the answer as an answer please.

Comment: For the error messages: It is 342 200 234 (octal) → 0xE2 0x80 0x9C (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+201C ([LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9)). And 342 200 235 (octal) → 0xE2 0x80 0x9D (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+201D ([RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9)). They can be searched for (and replaced) using the regular expression `\x{201C}|\x{201D}`.

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Comment: What is "notepad" in the title? Windows' [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Notepad)? [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B)? Why is Atom then mentioned in the body and not Windows' Notepad? We [may never know](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients) as the OP has left the building (*"Last seen more than 3 years ago"*).

Comment: Note: The notation is different in Visual Studio Code (and probably others): `\u201C|\u201D`

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing the variable a, which is an int, not an array. Also, in the while loop, you are only accessing the first element of array arr (because i is 0),  and you are assingnig allways a's value, that's not set anywhere. You should check f.fail() after reading into ch or at least do something like

```
std::array<int, 2> arr;

for(int i = 0; (std::cin >> ch) && i < arr.size(); ++i) {
    arr[i];
}
```

If you don't know in advance how many numbers you have to read use `std::vector` instead and `push_back` the values.

Comment: Addressing the last error reported by the compiler is usually not an effective way to resolve the errors. In this case the last error is independent of the the earlier ones, but often the later errors are artifacts, existing only because the compiler got confused by the earlier errors.

Comment: In this case it is certainly an error.

Comment: Yes, we are in agreement that it is an error, but you missed the point. Imagine you are responding to someone who does not understand the error messages. How would you justify ignoring the earlier errors? What would tell this person that the earlier errors can be ignored?

Comment: The first comment to the post already pointed out that non-ascii quotes were used. I supposed it was already clear and so just focused in other errors present.